# Confusion about the Lebesgue spaces on Riemannian manifolds

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Having taken a few courses on measure theory and Riemannian geometry, I still fail to make a successful access to the Lebesgue space $L^p(M)$ on a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$. In the 1987 article *THE YAMABE PROBLEM* authored by Lee and Parker, $L^p(M)$ is defined to be the set of locally integrable functions $u$ on $M$ for which the norm
$$\lVert u\rVert_p=\left(\int_M|u|^p dV_g\right)^\frac{1}{p}$$
is finite. This definition is not for the authors' exclusive use and can be commonly found in the literature, but the motivation to consider the integral
$$\int_M|u|^p dV_g$$
is totally mysterious to me. According to *Measure and Integral: An Introduction to Real Analysis* by Wheeden and Zygmund, constructing Lebesgue spaces requires a measure space, which is not a problem in our present case because the Riemannian metric $g$ induces a distance function on $M$ and hence helps us build an outer measure. Then it would be natural to define integrals by using this very outer measure. If this is the case, why would I have to consider the integral
$$\int_M|u|^pdV_g$$
using the Riemannian volume form, not to mention that $|u|^p$ may not be compactly supported? Can someone give me an idea of what's going on in the formation of $L^p(M)$? Thanks for everything.

Update: Thank you all, and I was astounded to know that if one is to have a well-defined distance function on $M$, then $M$ has to be connected in order that any two points of $M$ can be joined by a piecewise smooth curve segment. Maybe that's why I should refrain myself from using the outer measure induced by the Riemannian distance function.

Comment: Isn't the Riemannian volume form defines a measure space already?

Comment: "but the motivation to consider the integral $∫M|u|^p\,dVg$ is totally mysterious to me", why is misterious to you? It is the natural notion of an $L^p$ space! Note that, locally, the volume form can be seen as an orthogonal projection of an standard volume form in $\mathbb{R}^m$, where the latter is identical to the Lebesgue measure

Comment: First of all, the Riemannian volume form induces a borealian measure $\mu_g$ given by $\mu_g(A) = \int_A dV_g$. Secondly, indeed $\int_M|u|^p dV_g$ can be infinite: this is also the case for the standard Lebesgue-measure on $\Bbb R^n$; but the $L^p$ space is defined as the space of $u$ such that this quantitiy **is** finite!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $(M,g)$ be a pseudo-Riemannian manifold. The metric tensor $g$ [gives rise](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4210663/568204) to a unique positive measure $\lambda_g$ defined on the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra, $\mathscr{L}(M)$, of $M$ such that it has the desired formula in terms of a chart (see the link for details). It is also common to denote this measure as $V_g$ or $\mu_g$ (or $dV_g$ or $d\mu_g$, or even $dA_g$ if you’re talking about submanifolds of codimension one, or one might even suppress $g$ in the notation).

Now we have a measure space $(M, \mathscr{L}(M), \lambda_g)$, in the strict real-analysis measure-theory sense, so all that theory carries over verbatim. In particular, for $p\in [1,\infty]$, we can define the Lebesgue spaces $L^p(M)\equiv L^p(\lambda_g)\equiv L^p(M,\mathscr{L}(M),\lambda_g)$, which are Banach spaces as usual.

A remark about notation: we often overload the notation so that $dV_g$ denotes the measure induced by $g$, or alternatively on an **oriented** manifold it is also used to denote the induced volume $n$-form. In the oriented case the integral of an $L^1$ function $u$ with respect to the measure $dV_g$ is equal to the integral of the $L^1$ differential$n$-form $u\,dV_g$ (if you’re worried about integrating differential forms of non-compact support, take a look at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4403019/568204)). The fact that these are equal follows immediately by unwinding definitions (of the measure and of the volume $n$-form).

Comment: Note that a separate question is whether on a connected Riemannian $n$-manifold $(M,g)$, the Riemann-Lebesgue measure $\lambda_g$ as introduced here coincides with the $n$-dimensional Hausdorff measure $H_g$ induced by the distance metric $d_g$ on $M$. I *believe* the answer is yes (perhaps Riemann normal coordinates will be helpful) but it’s been a while since I thought about this so off the top of my head I’m not sure.

Comment: Yeah, I'm especially interested in why we don't use the Riemannian distance approach and whether or not this approach is equivalent to the one you mentioned. After looking it up in my reference at hand, I found Dan A. Lee giving an affirmative reply as to the latter question. He didn't explain specifically how to prove it though because some tedious work was intentionally avoided.

Comment: @Wombat one reason I don't like the distance version is because on Lorentzian manifolds (the heart of GR) the metric tensor no longer induces a distance function, so this approach isn't generalizable, while the volume approach in the link still works. In fact it works with any $(0,2)$ tensor field (e.g also with the symplectic 2-form on a symplectic manifold).